# im(A) contained in im(B) and their ranks are same, how to show their images are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have

im(A) contained in im(B), and that rank(A) = rank(B).

It seems pretty obvious to me that im(A) = im(B), but I can't quite put it into rigorous proof.

Could someone help me find an elegant proof for this? Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider the quotient space $\;\operatorname{Im}B/\operatorname{Im}A$. What can you say about a vectorspace of dimension $0$?